# Disable self sign-in to wso2 emm

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot, wso2-identity-server

I have installed WSO2 EMM, everything works as it should.

I want to disable the Self Sign-up option on the Management Console, accessible on https://192.168.63.220:9443/carbon/admin/login.jsp.

I have uninstalled the Self Registration Feature in the management console, and I also have set "Enabled" to "false" in the api-manager.xml. Nevertheless, the option for Self Registration is still available.

How do I disable this option?

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling Self Registration feature from carbon console will remove the registration link from the UI. But make sure to restart your server after removing the feature.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to configure anything to disable the Self-Registration. All you need to do is uninstalling the Self-Registration feature from EMM server & restarting the server. If the "Self-signup" is still visible please reload the page again after clearing the browser cache.

Regards,

Harshan